# Can I alter the result of DNS resolution for a VPS?

Tags: dns, ip, web, vps

I have a VPS hosted by a no frills provider and have an IP that I log into through SHH. When I run a traceroute on it, the final hop identifies the location service as ip-somebrand.com.

As my ipv4 address is unique to my VPS, is there a way to change the DNS hostname of the final hop?

Do I need to register a top level domain to do this?

Comment: I believe this is reverse DNS not regular DNS.  Therefore it needs to be configured with your VPS provider.  Many providers (such as AWS) give you access this through your control panel.

Comment: Ask or check if your vps

Comment: What are you trying to do: change output of traceroute?, or something else?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I want to change the output of traceroute, yes.